# Multiple log in handle by servlets

Tags: java, security, servlets, web

I have a small webapp based on servlets and jabsorb. There are two types of users in my app - managers and regular users. Managers can edit users and delete them.

How should I handle the next situation:

- I logged in as a manager1.
- Then I open other tab in a browser and log out and log in as a manager2.
- Then as I go to the tab with manager1 logged in and delete manager2.

I should not let it happen so how can I handle that with java servlets?

Comment: Please post the code that you have attempted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to decide how you want to handle the situation.

Off the top of my head, I can think of a couple of options:

- Let manager 1 delete manager 2 without any warning, but invalidate the session and any data for manager 2, so that the next time you try to do anything in the tab for manager 2, you'll get a message that you've been logged out, and be redirected to the login page. This is probably the simplest solution, since you won't have to do anything "extra" for manager 2; his login-session should just "*die*" on its own as a result of his account being disabled.
- When trying to delete manager 2, manager 1 will get a warning saying that manager 2 is currently logged in. Now you can either let manager 1 delete manager 2 anyway, or deny manager 1 the right to delete manager 2 until he has logged out - possibly with the added option of letting manager 1 forcibly log manager 2 out. This option will require a little more work, but not too much.

Anyway, once you clarify exactly how you want to handle the situation, finding out how to solve it in code should be easier. For more help, I think you should add some code and try to ask a more specific question.